# How to order matrix blocks in reverse

Tags: matrix, sorting, order

I've using a matrix field from the same entry in two different templates. In one template I want them in the order they're displaying in the CMS, while in the other I want them displayed in reverse.

It doesn't like this:

```
{% for cta in entry.ctas.order('desc') %}
```

Can this be done any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went and looked at the [MatrixBlockModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/matrixblockmodel); there's an attribute named [sortOrder](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/matrixblockmodel#sortOrder) (If you output `{{sortOrder}}` inside the `for` loop, it will display the index of that block).

You can use that attribute to sort by, in reverse:

```
{% for cta in entry.ctas.order('sortOrder desc') %}
```